# Adjacent links are not separated properly,bootstrap

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-modal

I try to make a html page bootstrap compatible. So that the layout will not change, but that it is valid bootstrap.And I mean with valid, that it will not say: "Adjacent links are not separated properly". I validate the page with: `http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php`  This is the html page:

```
{request.mapparams(p)}
<se:format inputdata="{translation.arg(dtIn)}">
    <se:rowformat expression="this.field(param)==request.query(p, default='')"><a class="list-group-item active" href="{url.addparameter(channel.link(this.field(Nr)), p, this.field(param))}"><span class="badge">{this.field(Count)}</span>{this.field(Title)}</a></se:rowformat>
    <se:rowformat><ul><a class="list-group-item"  href="{url.addparameter(channel.link(this.field(Nr)), p, this.field(param))}"><span class="badge">{this.field(Count)}</span>{this.field(Title)}</a></ul></se:rowformat>
    <se:resultformat><div class="list-group">{this.result()}</div></se:resultformat>
</se:format>
```

I addes the ul element to this:

```
<ul><a class="list-group-item"  href="{url.addparameter(channel.link(this.field(Nr)), p, this.field(param))}"><span class="badge">{this.field(Count)}</span>{this.field(Title)}</a></ul>
```

but now the layout changed. How to change it that the layout will not be changed?

Thank you

For example if I do this:

```
{request.mapparams(p)}
<se:format inputdata="{translation.arg(dtIn)}">
    <se:rowformat expression="this.field(param)==request.query(p, default='')"><a class="list-group-item active" href="{url.addparameter(channel.link(this.field(Nr)), p, this.field(param))}"><span class="badge">{this.field(Count)}</span>{this.field(Title)}</a></se:rowformat>
    <se:rowformat><li><span style="visibility:hidden"></span><a class="list-group-item"  href="{url.addparameter(channel.link(this.field(Nr)), p, this.field(param))}"><span class="badge">{this.field(Count)}</span>{this.field(Title)}</a><span style="visibility:hidden"></span></li></se:rowformat>
    <se:resultformat><div class="list-group">{this.result()}</div></se:resultformat>
</se:format>
```

I still see a black dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved like this:

```
{request.mapparams(p)}
<se:format inputdata="{translation.arg(dtIn)}">
    <se:rowformat expression="this.field(param)==request.query(p, default='')"><a class="list-group-item active" href="{url.addparameter(channel.link(this.field(Nr)), p, this.field(param))}"><span class="badge">{this.field(Count)}</span>{this.field(Title)}</a></se:rowformat>
    <se:rowformat><li class="list-unstyled"><span style="visibility:hidden"></span><a class="list-group-item"  href="{url.addparameter(channel.link(this.field(Nr)), p, this.field(param))}"><span class="badge">{this.field(Count)}</span>{this.field(Title)}</a><span style="visibility:hidden"></span></li></se:rowformat>
    <se:resultformat><ul class="list-group">{this.result()}</ul></se:resultformat>
</se:format>
```

So problem solved :)